# merge csv files by first column

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv, columns, join

I have 3 csv files like this.

csv 1:

```
1,aaaa,bbb,2014-04-01
2,qwe,rty,2014-04-03
3,zxc,cvb,2014-04-05
```

csv 2:

```
2,j,k,2014-04-01
3,a,s,2014-04-04
5,g,h,2014-04-08
```

csv 3:

```
2,a,s,d,f,g,2014-04-01
3,d,f,g,h,j,2014-04-06
4,c,v,b,n,m,2014-04-09
```

**How can I merge all by the first column?**

```
SELECT * FROM csv1
JOIN csv2 where csv1[0]= csv2[0] --[0] is the position of the first column
```

The output should be:

```
 csv1 fields     | csv2 fields |  csv4 fields

 2,qwe,rty,2014-04-03,a,s,2014-04-04,a,s,d,f,g,2014-04-01
 3,zxc,cvb,2014-04-05,g,h,2014-04-08,d,f,g,h,j,2014-04-06
```

Comment: Your desired output appears to mix up the values e.g. line `3` has `g,h` from line `5` of `csv2` - is that what you intended? And what is `csv4`?

Comment: Just found a SQL engine over CSV files: https://github.com/harelba/q

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions in a single post. Post a separate question for each issue instead. Since I see that [you _have_ posted](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/143982/22222) your 2nd question separately, I am deleting it from here.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this entirely with [POSIX-specified features of `join`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/join.html).

```
join -t, csv[12] | join -t, - csv3
```

Using your `csv1`, `csv2` and `csv3` files as posted, that gives:

```
$ join -t, csv[12] | join -t, - csv3
2,qwe,rty,2014-04-03,j,k,2014-04-01,a,s,d,f,g,2014-04-01
3,zxc,cvb,2014-04-05,a,s,2014-04-04,d,f,g,h,j,2014-04-06
```

Comment: user3696932 did post an answer instead of a comment to comment your answer. Please take a look at the updated, edited question containing this comment, if you already haven't done so.