# Merge csv files with conditions

Tags: bash, awk, csv, join

I have 2 *CSV* files for each date (*csv_2014_4_15* and *csv_2014_4_16*) , with basic structure and couple of unique columns as below.

```
id,name,created_at,updated_at,other columns

12, joe, 2013-1-1 18:30, 2014-2-1 12:00
56, bob, datetime, datetime
```

I want to merge the 2 csv files based on these these conditions. My code so far is as below.

```
if (csv_date_x.id == csv_date_x+1.id)
{
   if(csv_date_x.updated_at < csv_date_x.updated_at)
         add csv_date_x+1 row into out.csv
}
else {
   if(csv_date_x+1.created_at == TODAY (yyyy-mm-dd)
         add csv_date_x+1 row into out.csv
}
```

Comment: If both condition is false, the line in `csv_date_x` will print?

Comment: No, nothing will be printed

Comment: Lots of ambiguity in this question. You don't say for example if there is at most a single instance of 'id' in each file, or if they are sorted. I assume that by csv_date_x you mean csv_2014_4_15 and csv_date_x+1 means csv_2014_4_16. But according to your pseudo-code you never use any lines from csv_date_x, so that's more a filter than a merge and you wind up with a subset of csv_2014_4_16.

Comment: I am sorry for the ambiguities, but it seems you understood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ awk -F',' -v t="$(date +"%Y-%-m-%-d")" '
    FNR == NR {
        u[$1] = $4;
        next;
    }
    $4 > u[$1] {
        print;
        next;
    }
    t ~ $3
' file_1 file_2
```

**Explanation**

- We get today date, save it in variable `t`
- While reading file_1 `FNR == NR`, we save each updated time of each id in associative array `u`, key is id, value is updated time.
- While reading file_2:

  - If update date of id, `$4` greater than correspond id updated time save in array `u` (`$4 > u[$1]`), we print the line and skip to next line.
  - If above condition false, we check if created date of current line is today, `t ~ $3`, i.e `"2014-7-11" ~ "2014-7-11 12:00"`, if true print the line.

Comment: Can you please explain how this works ?

Comment: FNR==NR compares the ids ? and in the first scope you create 2 arrays with the dates ? c=csv_x 3rd column ? and u = csv_x+1 4th column ? and in the second scope you compare the dates?

Comment: @user3696932: I updated my answer, remove unnecessary things.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that by csv_date_x you mean csv_2014_4_15 and csv_date_x+1 means csv_2014_4_16. But according to your pseudo-code you never use any lines from csv_date_x, so that's more a filter than a merge and you wind up with a subset of csv_2014_4_16.

This is a non-trivial programming task, but I can point you in a profitable direction.

This sort of thing can get hairy if you have to deal with escaped commas in the first two fields. I'll assume that you do not.

I'll also assume that you can compare these two files row-by-row, since you didn't specify.

You'll need to first normalize your csv files so that months and dates are always two digits (leading zeros). Then they can be compared textually, and this is pretty easy with `awk`. Something like:

```
sed 's/-\([1-9]\)/-0\1/'
```

(this assumes you have no hyphens in your names, ids, or "other columns", you'll need a different approach if so, probably matching more carefully on date patterns and possibly restricting to the 3rd and 4th fields).

Use the `date` program to generate today's date in the output format that matches your fields, and pass that in as a variable for `awk` to use:

```
awk -v Today=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") -v File1=csv_2014_4_15 -v File2=csv_2014_4_16 '
{ getline line1 < File1;
  getline line2 < File2;
  split(line1, f1, ",");
  split(line2, f2, ",");
}
f1[1] == f2[1] { ...; next } # compare IDs this is your first 'if' clause
{ ... } # this is your else clause since the previous ended with "next"
```

You're in pretty good shape at that point. f1 contains the fields of the line from File1, and f2 contains the fields of the line from File2. You can compare ids (e.g. f1[1] and f2[1]) and dates (e.g. f1[2] for create f1[3] for update). and print the lines you want. You can compare against `Today` for today's date.

Note that you could get fancier and do your date-format normalization within `awk` by splitting the 3rd and 4th fields on `-` but I'd find it easier with a `sed` pass first.

Also note that Today contains both date and time. If you just want to compare the date, you can drop that from the `date` command specification, but you'll also need to split the csv field to strip the time before comparing.